# Need to find last @ in the string using a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace old domain from email if matches, and if i want to include all pre @ then how to iterate till last @ and only from there remove old domain.
preferred output - demo@@@@.google.com

```
def replace_email(email,old_domain,new_domain):
    if "@"+old_domain in email:
        index = email.index("@")
        new_email = email[:index] +"@"+new_domain
        return new_email
    return email
print(replace_email('demo@@@@@drungston.com','drungston.com','google.com'))
print(replace_email('test@@@yahoo.com','yahoo.com','yahoo.com'))
```

Comment: Is there a single (or few) old domains that are being replaced? or do you want to do this for every/any domain?

Comment: You probably want to look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace (if you know the original domain that is being replaced at least).

Comment: If you want to replace `f"@{old_domain}"` with `f"@{new_domain}"`, why not do just that? `'demo@@@@@drungston.com'.replace("@drungston.com", "@google.com")` Note that your code has five `@` symbols, your description indicates that you want five `@` in your output, but your expected output only contains four

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a loop to find the last occurrence of a character in a string as you can simply use [`rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

```
def replace_email(email, old_domain, new_domain):
    if '@' in email:
        email = email[:email.rindex('@')] + email[email.rindex('@'):].replace(old_domain, new_domain) 
    return email
```

This will preserve the number of @ in your output (although, as noted above, your explanation doesn't match your preferred output).

```
print(replace_email('demo@@@@@drungston.com','drungston.com','google.com'))
demo@@@@@google.com
```

If you wanted to eliminate the excess @s, it would be as simple as changing `rindex` to `index` in the first half of the function.

```
def replace_email(email, old_domain, new_domain):
    if '@' in email:
        email = email[:email.index('@')] + email[email.rindex('@'):].replace(old_domain, new_domain) 
    return email
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the domain in the email:

```
def email_to_domain(email):
    emailarr = email.split('@')
    return emailarr[len(emailarr)-1]
```

Example for test@google.com -> google.com

```
email = "test@google.com"
def email_to_domain(email):
    emailarr = email.split('@')
    return emailarr[len(emailarr)-1]
print(email_to_domain(email))
```

The above should print google.com.
Hope its useful to you.